# python an integer is required in replace

Tags: python, python-2.7

this is my code

```
for date in self.getDateRange():
          date = date.replace('-','/')
```

and this is the getDateRange function:

```
def getDateRange(self):
    from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
    return self.perdelta(date(2000, 01, 01), date(2015, 8, 03), timedelta(days=1))

def perdelta(self, start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta
```

and this is the error message

```
MySpider.py", line 19, in parse
            date = date.replace('-','/')
        exceptions.TypeError: an integer is required
```

it is weird, i always able to do the replace, without any problem, i don't know why is here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're operating on actual `date` objects which [have their own `replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects):

> ```
> date.replace(year, month, day)
> ```
>
> Return a date with the same value, except for those parameters given new values by whichever keyword arguments are specified. For example, if d == date(2002, 12, 31), then d.replace(day=26) == date(2002, 12, 26).

That methods only takes integers. If you want to work on dates as strings, you need to convert them. But since you already have objects, you can just format them with a slash as a separator using `strftime()`.

Comment: i don't need option of date, i need string of date in this format `04/08/2015`

Comment: could you give me example please

Comment: Then you can just do `yield curr.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` in the `perdelta()` function (update format however you need it).

Answer (score 0):

The objects in your list are not strings. They are datetime objects (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

You should use date.strftime to output your date in whatever format you'd like. Refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior for the full formatting options.

For example, you might want date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')